# reading weblogic.xml from a location external to war

Tags: weblogic11g

I have deployed 2 web applications in oracle weblogic 11gR1. For both of these applications i wanted to configure weblogic.xml in an external location such as in domain home.

Is there any way this can be achieved or is it mandatory for weblogic.xml to be present in WEB-INF folder within the WAR file?

Answer (score 0):

A Deployment Plan (plan.xml file) located outside the war could be used to modify values in weblogic.xml. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/config.html